# How to oracle sqlplus bottom title page number format change as 3 digits

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have already used

```
btitle left 'Report Date:' report_date center 'PAGE:' FORMAT 999 SQL.PNO right 'Username:SYSTEM'
```

this code. but there is not working. therefore please help me immediately.

I want to change this mentioned page number format as '002'

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO Nuwan. I appreciate your eagerness to be assisted but "therefore please help me immediately." might not be the best approach. Please can you share more detail about your problem so others are inclined to help you.

Comment: Thank you Mike for your support. I'll send the problem again.

Comment: Glad to help. You can edit your question instead of asking it again.

Answer (score 0):

Don't format it as `999` but `000`:

```
SQL> btitle left 'Report Date:' report_date center 'PAGE:' FORMAT 000 SQL.PNO right 'Username:SYSTEM'
SQL> select * From dept;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON






Report Date:report_date             PAGE: 001                    Username:SYSTEM

SQL>
```